# Should we answer questions that do not show any research, any code, or any effort?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, asking-questions

I have observed a few times that a question is asked which is fairly easy to solve. But it doesn't show any research effort and there is no code, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745758/how-to-change-wpf-listview-header-background-color?noredirect=1#comment57237288_34745758) question.

This seems to especially happen when the OP doesn't understand how SO works.

If there is an answer provided to such a question, should it be flagged?

Comment: looks like I didn't put enough effort lol

Comment: Go search for "help vampires" and read.